# Who coined the word Hinduism?

Tags: india

The word **Hinduism** is very popular, but who used it first?

There are some references in during British era ,but when exactly this word was used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is from the time of Indo-Aryans when the the ancient Indus river was called 'Sindhu'. 
Now there was some language which you pronounce 's' as 'h', so when the people speaking this language came to India, they called the river Sindhu and people living beyond the river as 'Hindu'. (I've read it in a book I can't remember)
And they also say that Hindu is Urdu for Hind which is Persian. 
So basically, it is all related to the Indus river being called as Sindhu. Somehow, over a period of time it may have changed from Hind to Hindu or from Sindhu to Hindu directly. But that's where it originated.
While Hinduism refers to the ancient religion that we have, it is however not related to the religion itself. It is just a name to refer to the religion. And at present, there is a vast confusion over this term. People claim to be 'hindu' referring to being an 'Indian' and while Hindu is thought to be related the religion Hinduism, muslims in India today feel a confusion over it. There is an identity crises, if I may, at this time in India.